# .Net core Socket connection to localhost websocket server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

So I followed this simple guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets) to create an Asp.Net Core application that accepts websocket connections. I am running the code from the command line using dotnet .\name.dll. My app starts and says that it is running.

I wrote another .Net core application that is trying to connect into this web server and I cannot seem to get the connection to start. I get host unknown from the socket.Connect() method.

The ws://localhost/ws port 5000 is coming from the command line when I run my server it reports to be listening there.

All my client code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to localhost ...");

        Socket s = new Socket(SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);

        s.Connect("ws://localhost/ws", 5000);

        s.Send(EncodeData("Hello World"));

        byte[] textBuffer = new byte[4*1024];
        s.Receive(textBuffer);
        ConvertToConsole(textBuffer);

        Console.WriteLine("Closing on any key press.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ConvertToConsole(byte[] data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
    }

    private static byte[] EncodeData(String text)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    }
```

Comment: I found out that the Socket class may not be what I wanted. There is actually a ClientWebSocket class deeper into the System.Net.WebSockets namespace.

Comment: Your code is for a client using the  s.Connect() method.  You need to listen :  TcpListener s = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);

Comment: What if I want to send and receive?

Comment: Websockets is a protocol like http. You cannot just connect with raw tcp like you are trying now and expect it to work.

Comment: A one connection will support both send/receive.  The server is started first using Listen() and the client is started second using Connect().